# Bypassing Read-only HTML elements in Selenium for Python?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a task I am attempting to automate in selenium using Python, which includes selecting a date. The date selection on the website has an input box that when you select drops down a pretty standard date table.

The input "text" box is set to read-only and I am having some trouble getting Selenium to find the dates I am asking it to select, being able to simply send_keys of the date required to the input box would be a far easier implementation.

After some research, I found this solution in JS:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].value=arguments[1]", element, "my text to put in the value");
```

Is there a similar function I could use in Python that would achieve the same?

I am not that familiar with Javascript so my abilities don't allow me to convert this into Python.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same function exists in selenium python and is accessible from the driver object:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value=arguments[1]", element, "my text to put in the value")
```

You say you don't know javascript, so a quick outline for you...

You're passing 3 variables to `execute_script`:

- First one is the js to execute `arguments[0].value=arguments[1]`. This look for 2 input arguments. It sets the `.value` of the first input with the value of the second input
- `element` is the next variable you pass in and is first js argument (`argument[0]`) and is your webelement you've already identified
- `"my text...blah"` is the second argument (`argument[1]`) and is the string value you want to set

More info on this method and others can be found in [python-selenium docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html).

Execute script is covered as such:

> execute_script(script, *args) Synchronously Executes JavaScript in the
> current window/frame.
>
> Args:  script: The JavaScript to execute.
> *args: Any applicable arguments for your JavaScript. Usage:    driver.execute_script(‘return document.title;’)

Answer (score 0):

The [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) [python](/questions/tagged/python) client equivalent line of code will be:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value=arguments[1]", element, "my text to put in the value")
```

> It is to be noted the *JavaScript* command part remains the same and only the method name varies as per the binding art, be it *Java*, *Python*, *C#*, etc.